# SIGABRT received while using KeychainItemWrapper iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, keychain, sigabrt

I'm writing an application that uses the class "KeychainItemWrapper" for storing in a secure way login credentials. Here's the code that manages the Keychain object:

```
- (IBAction)saveFields {
wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"username" accessGroup:nil];
[wrapper setObject:[self.password text] forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[wrapper release];
wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"password" accessGroup:nil];
[wrapper setObject:[self.password text] forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[wrapper release];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)isUserLogged {
wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"username" accessGroup:nil];
if ( [[wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    return NO;
} else {
    username = [NSString stringWithString:[wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]];
    [wrapper release];
}
wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"password" accessGroup:nil];
if ( [[wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    return NO;
} else {
    password = [NSString stringWithString:[wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]];
    [wrapper release];
}

return YES;
}
```

I receive the SIGABRT error when I try to write credentials in the keychain, here:

```
// KeychainItemWrapper.m
// - (void)writeToKeychain;
result = SecItemAdd( (CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the fault was on the NSAssert() block. Commenting the line solved the problem.

Comment: What `NSAssert()` block? I can't see one in the code in the question.

Comment: Actually I can't remember, I should get the whole project back and look at it, I'll do it on monday.